# Proof checking of Well-Definiteness of Multiplication of Ordinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, ordinals

**proof**

First, define $A_1 \approxeq A_2 \iff ord(A_1) = ord(A_2)$

$\forall \ \text{well-ordered sets}\; A,B  \;\text{s.t.} A\cap B=\varnothing$ and $ord(A) = \alpha,\; ord(B)= \beta$,

define $\alpha\beta = ord(A\times B)$ where $A\times B$ denotes anti-lexicographic-order between A and B.

Then take well-ordered set $A', B'$ s.t. $A\cap B=\emptyset\;$ and $ord(A') = \alpha,\; ord(B')= \beta$.

Then since $ord(A') = ord(A)$ and $ord(B') = ord(B)$,

$A' \approxeq A$ and $B \approxeq B'$, which means

$\exists g: A \to A'$ and $\exists h: B \to B'$ s.t.

$\forall x,y \in A, x \le y \Rightarrow g(x) \le g(y)$

and $\forall x,y \in B, x \le y \Rightarrow h(x) \le h(y)$

and $\forall x,y \in A', x \le y \Rightarrow g^{-1}(x) \le g^{-1}(y)$

and $\forall x,y \in B', x \le y \Rightarrow h^{-1}(x) \le h^{-1}(y)$

Now define $f:A \times B \to A' \times B'$ s.t.

$f(x,y) = (g(x), h(y)) \forall x \in A$ and $\forall y \in B$

Then $\forall (x,y)\;$and $(x',y') \in A \times B$

$(x,y) \le (x',y') \Rightarrow f(x,y) \le f(x',y')$ since $g(x) \le g(x')$ and $h(y) \le h(y')$

Similarly,

$\forall (x,y)\;$and $(x',y') \in A' \times B'$,

$(x,y) \le (x',y') \Rightarrow f^{-1}(x,y) \le f^{-1}(x',y')$ since $g^{-1}(x) \le g^{-1}(x')$ and $h^{-1}(y) \le h^{-1}(y')$.

Thus, $A \times B \approxeq A' \times B'$,  which menas

$ord(A\times B) = ord(A'\times B')$

Thus, $ord(A'\times B') = \alpha\beta$ Q.E.D.

Comment: A little latex hint, "varnothing" is better than "emptyset". I have replaced the first one  and left the others in order you see the difference.

Comment: @JeanMarie "Better" is highly subjective. I, for one, don't like \varnothing at all.

Comment: Your proof looks fine to me. But you should state that $g,h$ are injective in order for $g^{-1}, h^{-1}$ to be well-defined and respect the respective order.

Comment: @Stefan I agree about the subjectiveness. Just because i find "emptyset" "too slim"... having been close to starvation in its chidhood...